# getchar()で1文字入力してもdo-whileが2回実行されてしまう

Tags: c

下記のコードで例えば `p` と入力すると、なぜか `dayo` が二回表示されてしまいます。
do while の仕様はいったいどういうものなのでしょうか？

入力を含んだ処理を一回やったあとに含まない処理をもう一度しているようにみえます。
よろしくお願いします。

環境：
Ubuntu
gcc 7.5.0

---

**出力結果:**

```
p
p dayo

dayo
```

**ソースコード:**

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c;

    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%c dayo\n",c);

    } while (c != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 蛇足ですが、このコードを実行して EOF(Control-D)だけを入力すると無限ループになってしまいます。その点も考慮すると良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p`を入力するとき、改行も入力していませんか？
そうであれば、`p`と改行でwhileループが２回実行されています。
`p`のあと`^d`(ctrl+d)を入力すれば`p`だけを入力することになり、想定した動作をするはずです。

Comment: なりました！　ありがとうございました。

Comment: 入力がそのようなことになっているとは知らなかったです。

Comment: getchar()は標準入力から1文字づつデータを読み込みますが、今回のケースではpを読み込んだ後、改行コードが残っていて、次のループで改行コードを読み込みます。

Comment: 理解できました。